# What is the range that weights can be for activation functions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am creating my own neural network and want to know how the weights relate to activation functions. I have coded the logistic and tanh activation functions and want to know if the weights that are attached to the individual neurons have to be different regarding each function. Right now I have the range of weights of the logistic activation function from 0 to 1 and tanh as -1 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you limit the weights? I think your muddled up somewhere. This is how the output of a neuron is determined:

`var output = ActivationFunction(every(connection.weight * connection.from.output) + bias)`

So make a sum of all the incoming weights and their source values, add the bias, and pass it throught he activation function.

**Yes**, the sigmoid is limited between `0` and `1`. But why would you limit your weights because of that? The value of the weights is nowhere linked to the activation function.

Limiting your weights to such small ranges (`0` to `1` is a miniscule range) will make your network unable to solve certain patterns.